# Unwanted Extra Pages for Koma Script Title Pages with Graphics

Tags: koma-script, titles, titling

Komascript. Book class.

I'm trying to use a graphic on (as) my title page but it throws two extra empty pages that I can't get rid of. The order should be:

1-half title page

2-title page

3-lower title back (with copyright info)

and then the ToC and the rest of the main matter.

Instead, I'm getting:

1- half title page

2- title page

3- blank page

4- another blank page

5- \lowertitleback page

and then the ToC and the rest of the document.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,fontsize=9pt,BCOR=2cm,headlines=2.5,usegeometry]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
%\extratitle{\textbf{\Huge Me}}
\begin{titlepage}
\includegraphics{i.jpeg}
\title{}
\date{}
\end{titlepage}
%\extratitle{\textbf{\Huge In Love}} \title{In Love}
%\author{}
%\date{}

\cleardoublepage
\lowertitleback{
    \textit{A Boring Book}
    ©2022 Anyname, Inc. 
    All Rights Reserved. Batteries not included. Kids, do not try this at home.    Professional driver on closed course. Past performance is no guarantee of future results.  
\medskip

\noindent ISBN: 1234567

\noindent ePub: 12345678
}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Apparently (see discussion below) the issue is caused by the size of the added graphic, even though that graphic is a4 sized, the same papersize used (and the default!) in the Koma classes. When I add the full page a4 title page to this MWE (before I used a placeholder for the MWE only--it throws the unwanted extra pages, which defy suppression. It seems odd that Markus Kohm would recommend creating an external title page in the German manual but not explain how to accomplish that feat. Any ideas?

I tried using \usepackage{includepdf} thusly:

```
\extratitle{
\includepdf{halfpage.pdf}
}
```

which put the half title on the second page and left the first page blank!

Comment: If I delete the \begin{title page}...\end{titlepage} and put this text in a separate file (called titlepage, no extension) and then change \maketitle to \input{titlepage} the extra pages disappear, but so does the \lowertitleback and associated text. I tried moving \input{titlepage} to both before and after \lowertitleback but it made no difference; the copyright info was gone.

Comment: Once upon a time Komascript recommended creating title pages in a separate graphics program, but I can't find this anymore in the manual. Nor how and in what order to place such an externally-created page.

Comment: At least the German version of the docs still recommends that “in general, a book cover is something that is created in a separate document. After all, it often has a very individual shape. There is nothing wrong with using a graphics or DTP program for this …” Not sure that part actually made it in the English translation, though.

Comment: @Ingmar That's what I remember, but I couldn't find it in the current translation or worse, an example of its use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add an external created title page, you should not use `\maketitle`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn,fontsize=9pt,BCOR=2cm,headlines=2.5,DIV=calc,usegeometry]{scrbook}
\usepackage{pdfpages}% loads graphicx
\usepackage{mwe}% example-images and dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\noindent
\parbox{\linewidth}{%
  \color{red}\Huge Content of half-title page \par% dummy half title page
}

\cleardoubleoddpage
\includepdf[pages=1]{example-image-a4-numbered}% dummy title page

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent
\parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \textit{A Boring Book}
    ©2022 Anyname, Inc. 
    All Rights Reserved. Batteries not included. Kids, do not try this at home. Professional driver on closed course. Past performance is no guarantee of future results. 
\medskip

ISBN: 1234567

ePub: 12345678
}\par
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\addchap{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, but the half-title page is gone...

Comment: I have updated my answer to highlight the half-title page. It is the first page of the document followed by an empty backside. Then a dummy title page is included.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,fontsize=9pt,BCOR=2cm,headlines=2.5,usegeometry]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikzducks}  % strictly for duck purposes
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\extratitle{Ducks \& Ducking Through the Ages}
\title{
    \includegraphics[width=.85\textwidth]{example-image-duck} 
    \begin{center}Ducks \& Ducking Through the Ages\end{center}
}% end of title

\author{Nomen Nescio}
\date{} % keep empty if you don't want to show current date

\lowertitleback{
    \textit{A Boring Book}
    ©2022 Anyname, Inc. 
    All Rights Reserved. Batteries not included.

\medskip
\noindent ISBN: 1234567
\noindent ePub: 12345678
}% end of lowertitleback

\end{titlepage}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\addchap{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

This produces

1. the half-title,
2. an empty page (= the backside of half-title),
3. the title page with an image,
4. the backside of the title page with your colophon & ISBN, and finally
5. the TOC and the rest of your book.

If that is not what you want, i.e. you don't want any empty pages, choose a different class: `scrbook` is for duplex printing. (You can use the `twoside=off` option, too, but then `\lowertitleback` won't work either.)

Comment: When copying your answer to my MWE, I get what you do. But when I copy to my document, I don't. Without an \extratitle I still get two unwanted pages before the \lowertitle back page. The only difference I can see is that I am trying to use a full page, a4, graphic as the title page. Why this is throwing two extra pages, I can't figure out. Does the German version of the Koma manual explain how to use a single a4 page as the title page of a document?

Comment: And indeed, when I add the full page a4 title page to my MWE (before I used a placeholder for the MWE only--I get the extra pages, which defy suppression. It seems odd that Markus Kohm would recommend creating an external title page in the German manual but not explain how to accomplish that feat. Any ideas?

Comment: If I move the \include graphics command to the first line after \begin{document} and delete the \extratitle command (so losing the half-title page) then the extra pages disappear; the a4 graphic is truncated and will have to be scaled. A separate text-only title page is created with the lower title on the obverse.  I'd like to have a half-title page and this hack doesn't seem like much of a solution...

Comment: By including a full-size A4 image, you effectively no longer ask  LaTeX to create an A4 page for you, you provide your own … So why use \maketitle at all? ETA: What @esdd said.