# \lowertitleback ignored with KOMA scrbook

Tags: koma-script

In my project, the `\lowertitleback` command is ignored and I can't figure out why. MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}
        \centering
      
      \bigskip
        \vspace{4\baselineskip}
        {\Huge 2023 Book}\par 
        \vspace{2\baselineskip}
        
        \vspace{4\baselineskip}
        {\large\textsc{edited by\\[.5em]The Editor}}
        \vfill
     
    \end{titlepage}
    
    \lowertitleback{ 
    Here is some text.
    Copyright
    ISBN}
    
\chapter*{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[5]    

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are not using \maketitle to create the titlepage.

Comment: True. I am using the `\titlepage` environment instead. Creating a separate title page with a graphics program was recommended in both the German and English versions of the Koma-script guide. I understand that the advice is retained in the German version but is no longer in the English version. Nor is there an example in the English version. I can't figure out how to drop the graphic into a .tex file. Is there a way to make the `\titlepage` environment play nicely with Komascript? As you may recall, `\maketitle` threw unwanted behaviors: https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1624655

Comment: you can use titlepage, but then you will have to setup the text on the next page manually too.

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646354